# How to convert NEthereum's BigInteger balance from WEI to ETH?

Tags: nethereum, c#, .net

I'm using this simple code to get the balances with NEthereum:

```
using System;
using System.Numerics;

namespace TestConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static readonly BigInteger ethToWeiRatio = new BigInteger(1000000000000000000m);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var web3 = new Nethereum.Web3.Web3();
            var accountsTask = web3.Eth.Accounts.SendRequestAsync();
            accountsTask.Wait();
            var accounts = accountsTask.Result;
            foreach (var account in accounts)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("account " + account);
            }
            foreach (var account in accounts)
            {
                var balanceTask = web3.Eth.GetBalance.SendRequestAsync(account);
                balanceTask.Wait();
                var balance = balanceTask.Result;
                Console.WriteLine("account " + account + "; balance in wei: "
                                  + balance.Value);
            }
            foreach (var account in accounts)
            {
                var balanceTask = web3.Eth.GetBalance.SendRequestAsync(account);
                balanceTask.Wait();
                var balance = balanceTask.Result;
                Console.WriteLine("account " + account + "; balance in eth: "
                      + BigInteger.Divide(balance.Value, ethToWeiRatio));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first `foreach` loops work, but the 3rd doesn't. My guess was that the balances being printed in the second foreach are in Wei units, so I had to convert them to Eth. But when doing that, the result is 0 for both cases, which is wrong because the balances are different between the accounts.

This is the full output:

```
account 0xd74c7d19e3bff6b150f76cac754a65df3b23b755
account 0xa9f4a7d4d7a163bc9f45e2e1e216b7f40ce79af5
account 0xd74c7d19e3bff6b150f76cac754a65df3b23b755; balance in wei: 542316352000000000
account 0xa9f4a7d4d7a163bc9f45e2e1e216b7f40ce79af5; balance in wei: 300000000000000000
account 0xd74c7d19e3bff6b150f76cac754a65df3b23b755; balance in eth: 0
account 0xa9f4a7d4d7a163bc9f45e2e1e216b7f40ce79af5; balance in eth: 0
```

**UPDATE 1**: Just found an ugly workaround: `decimal.Parse(balance.Value.ToString())/10000000000000000m`.

**UPDATE 2**: Author of library recommended a new API: https://github.com/Nethereum/Nethereum/blob/master/src/Nethereum.Util/UnitConversion.cs (haven't tested it yet).

Comment: what language is this? C#?

Comment: NEthereum is a .NET library, so yes, it is C#

Answer (score 5):

There is a helper converter function in Web3, similar to one implemented in web3.js.

It can be used as following:

web3.Convert.ToWei() or web3.Convert.FromWei()

or as a static method Nethereum.Web3.Web3.Convert.ToWei() or Nethereum.Web3.Web3.Convert.FromWei()

please have a look at the code for the different overloads

https://github.com/Nethereum/Nethereum/blob/master/src/Nethereum.Util/UnitConversion.cs

Comment: Just tried your FromWei() method and it gives me same problem, returns 0. So I'll still need to use my workaround :(

Comment: Interesting that bigInteger does not do a proper division, ill test it later

Comment: Just realised converting from and to Wei does not handle the decimal places due to BigInteger. I have an implementation already done for decimals. https://github.com/Nethereum/Netherum.Maker/blob/master/Nethereum.Maker/MakerTokenConvertor.cs

Comment: this is in the TODO list.. to add to the convertor

Comment: URL is now 404 :P

Comment: In the NEthereum library this is a static method that can be called as `Nethereum.Web3.Web3.Convert.FromWei(<numberInWei>)`; It returns a decimal which the represents an eth value.

Comment: Thanks @ThorkilVærge edited to add more info.