# Why does etherscan.io API response with wrong balance?

Tags: explorers, etherscan, external-api

Let's take the following [company](https://etherscan.io/address/0x38355ab2667ed167cadcd132603bc6236c8295de). The current ETH Balance is `268,691.327038426 Ether`:

[image]

But [API](https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=balance&address=0x38355ab2667ed167cadcd132603bc6236c8295de&tag=latest) response `268698327038426745609145`:

[image]

As you can see API response does't contain floating point so the balance value is very big.

Is it bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it isn't a bug the balance is returned in weis not in The Ethers.

chek one of many conversion tools: https://etherconverter.online/

```
268705.32703842675 Ether = 268705327038426745609145 wei
```

the `","` is used to separate three digits (look at the amount in $).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could please help how can I convert wei -> Eth by using API? The thing is I need to display balance in my site and I can't do convertion by hand.

Comment: divide by 10^18 or just count 18 digit from right then take the rest as balance in Ether

Comment: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4194/how-to-convert-nethereums-biginteger-balance-from-wei-to-eth

Comment: Could you point me where the documentation describes that all values returned in wei units?

Comment: re: documentation [JSON RPC API eth_getBalance](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getbalance) and [web3 JavaScript API web3.eth.getBalance](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgetbalance)